# Java "No space left on device" but there is enough space on disk?

Tags: java, file-io, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to write files to the file system in a java programme but it fails with an exception throwing 'No space left on device' when df -h (and df -i) says otherwise.

Here is the output of df -h:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5.9G  4.0K  5.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  1.4M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda5       156G  139G  9.1G  94% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            5.9G  105M  5.8G   2% /run/shm
none            100M   28K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2       105G  102G  2.7G  98% /media/sam/System 
/dev/sda3       176G  163G   14G  93% /media/sam/Sam //where I'm trying to write
```

and here is the output of df -i:

```
Filesystem       Inodes    IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            1523763      552  1523211    1% /dev
tmpfs           1526458      584  1525874    1% /run
/dev/sda5      10362880  4750381  5612499   46% /
none            1526458        2  1526456    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            1526458        3  1526455    1% /run/lock
none            1526458      191  1526267    1% /run/shm
none            1526458       26  1526432    1% /run/user
/dev/sda2       3832820  1045155  2787665   28% /media/sam/System 
/dev/sda3      35769712 22090147 13679565   62% /media/sam/Sam //where I'm trying to write
```

I am trying to write files to /media/sam/Sam/. I have tried restarting my machine, unmounting and mounting again but no luck. Also in Java if I create a new file object inside /media/sam/Sam and print the usage information, it prints 0 as below:

```
File tweetFile = new File( "/media/sam/Sam/" + "test"  + ".txt" );
System.out.println( tweetFile.getTotalSpace()  ); // prints 0
System.out.println( tweetFile.getFreeSpace()/1000000000 ); // prints 0
System.out.println( tweetFile.getUsableSpace()/1000000000 ); // prints 0
```

Any help is really appreciated as I'm trying to fix this for the whole day and getting really frustrated.

**EDIT**
Here is the exact message thrown:

```
Exception: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
    at utils.FileUtil.writeToFile(FileUtil.java:64)
    at experiments.usinglists.tagbasedeval.ToindexTweetsForAUser.main(ToindexTweetsForAUser.java:36)
```

Comment: Can you print the exact error message

Comment: Does your application have permission to write to the target directory?

Comment: @ScaryWombat pls see the edit.

Comment: @EricM. it does and was working properly. In face if i try to create a file - touch test - in the terminal it fails as well saying " touch: cannot touch ‘test’: No space left on device".

Comment: So, wouldn't it be right to say that this problem is not related to programming in Java? Sounds like this question should be asked on superuser.com as it's not about programming but about using Unix systems.

Comment: You said it was working before. Do you remember what you might have done, run some app or command, or notice something else happened before it stopped working? If you cant even touch a file then its something in the file system not Java related.

Comment: I haven't done anything just kept running my code until it threw the exception. Maybe I should ask there..

Comment: @samsamara were you able to find the cause and solution?

Comment: @sattu I haven't :( this could be a serious bug wih JVM I guess.

Comment: It isn't plausibly a bug in the JVM.  The file system full error is returned by the OS.  The JVM just reports what the OS is telling it.  I suspect that there is something funky about the media device or the file system mounted on "/media/sam/Sam".  I concur with Erwin - this is really a `SuperUser` or `Unix` problem.  It isn't a programming problem.

Comment: Linux filesystems often reserve a certain percentage of their capacity for the root user (to avoid situations where a full system breaks down and not even root can log in to fix it). It seems like your disk has less than 10% disk space left, so you might be running into this (especially since you can't create files outside of Java either). That value [can be changed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why) and if your disk is not used as a system partition, you might not need that feature at all.

Comment: share us your linux distro and arch,  just run 'uname -a'.  there are logs under /var/log you can diagnose this neatly.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the Java Process was operating with a temp-directory, using default java.io.tmpdir (in my case /tmp).

I was expecting it to work in another partition. So maybe changing the default works:

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/media/sam/Sam/tmp
```

Comment: What you are describing is clearly a different problem.

Answer (score -3):

It looks like the issue might be related to inode usage. The filesystem is using 62% of its inodes and the directory where you are trying to write also has a high percentage of inodes in use - 22090147 of 35769712. You may need to free up some inode space in order to write the files. You can do this by deleting some existing files, moving them to another directory, or using a tool such as "tune2fs" to manually increase the number of inodes available on the filesystem.